# AJAX call returning 200 after 60 seconds even though server side process is still running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So im making an AJAX call like so:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'download',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    })
    .done(function(){
      console.log('This was a success')

    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('This was a fail')
    });
}
```

No matter what it will return a 200 after 60 seconds if the process is still running.

I don't think it can be a serverside issue as it's working as expected. Is there any browser or AJAX related timeout I should be taking into account?

Comment: What is the server-side process?

Comment: How big is your 'download' response? It may take a while to download large files

Comment: Check out the `timeout` property of the `$.ajax` request, **however** having a process running on a webserver for longer than 60 seconds is a terrible idea. Even 20 seconds would be pushing it. You should amend your logic if that's the case. I'd suggest making the request using AJAX which returns immediately then using websockets to keep track of it's status - assuming that's your use case here.

Comment: Even for timeout, the ajax should invoke error callback IMO.

Comment: It's polling on a response from another server. It works 100% fine, even after AJAX returns 20 i can see in the logs that's it continuing to work, and then finishes successfully.

Comment: Using websockets isn't an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a Browser issue.

Firefox 45 would timeout after 60 seconds and return a 200 success code, even though the server process was still running.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the timeout but is not a good idea , it's better to improve the logic on the server side

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'download',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    timeout: 60000 // sets timeout to 60 seconds
    })
    .done(function(){
      console.log('This was a success')

    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('This was a fail')
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the AJAX documentation you can add a timeout attribute:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'download',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    timeout: 0,
    })
    .done(function(){
      console.log('This was a success')

    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('This was a fail')
    });
}
```

> timeout=0 means no timeout limit

official docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/